# Does the resistance granted by the Horizon Walker ranger's Spectral Defense feature last for the entire turn it's activated?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, damage-resistance, duration

The [Horizon Walker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#HorizonWalker) ranger archetype from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* gains the [Spectral Defense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#SpectralDefense-727) class feature at 15th level (p. 43):

> At 15th level, your ability to move between planes enables you to slip
>   through the planar boundaries to lessen the harm done to you during
>   battle. When you take damage from an attack, you can use your reaction
>   to give yourself resistance to all of that attack's damage on this
>   turn.

Say an enemy attacks a Horizon Walker ranger with a *flame tongue* longsword and uses Divine Smite, giving the attack 3 different damage types.

If the ranger uses their reaction to use Spectral Defense, does that mean that for the rest of that turn, they have resistance to all 3 types of damage? If the enemy tries to do the same thing again, does the ranger still have resistance, since it says **for the turn**?

Answer (score 9):

### The resistance does not last for the rest of your turn

The Spectral Defense feature states:

> At 15th level, your ability to move between planes enables you to slip through the planar boundaries to lessen the harm done to you during battle. When you take damage from an attack, you can use your reaction to give yourself resistance to all of that attack's damage on this turn.

Compare this to something like the [*shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) which states:

> [...] Until the start of your next turn, you have a +5 bonus to AC, including against the triggering attack [...]

It explicitly states that you have the AC boost until the start of your next turn, which the Spectral Defense feature does not.

That said, the Spectral Defense feature *does* have incredibly unusual wording as it includes "on this turn". The only time I can see this having an effect if **the same attack** that damaged you later does *more* damage on that same turn. It also prevents *future* damage **from the same attack** that occurs on *later* turns from being resisted. I don't know when these niche scenarios would occur.

Comment: for the resistance to apply to future damage the future damage would have to be part of the original attack's damage note how it says "that attack's damage"

Comment: @ninjahX I believe I mentioned that: "It also prevents future damage *from the attack* that occurs on later turns from being resisted". I'm emphasized the relevant text now

Comment: Does poison damage dealt after a venomous attack get resisted too?

Comment: @Vylix that sounds like a great question to open up

Comment: The only situation I can think of where a character would take damage twice from the same attack on the same turn is very niche:  the horizon walker moving away from a character with Warcaster and Booming Blade. The way it is worded, the character would be resistant to the initial impact damage and the penalty-for-moving damage, because it's all one attack and it all happens on the same turn.

Comment: What's the point of putting in ""for the turn" then?

Comment: @ninjahX I explained the two reasons I could possibly imagine. Both are near-unoccuring circumstances so it really feels like there's some sort of mistake in the wording